# OS X Bash script doesn't work but individual commands do

Tags: bash, macos, shell, networking, vpn

I'm trying to turn the instructions on [this page](http://www.calvinfroedge.com/connecting-to-a-softether-vpn-server-as-client-from-osx-yosemite/) about connecting to a Soft Ether VPN on OS X into a bash script, but I'm running into some issues.

When I run each of these commands individually at the command line, I'm able to initiate the connection to the VPN just fine and set up the routing appropriately, but when I put it into a script, it doesn't work.

Here is the script in question:

```
#!/bin/bash
GATEWAY=`route -n get default | grep gateway | awk '{print $2}'`
VPN_IP=130.158.6.123/32
VPN_GATEWAY=192.168.0.1

vpnclient start
vpncmd localhost /CLIENT /CMD AccountConnect HomeVPN;
ipconfig set tap0 DHCP;
ifconfig tap0 down; ifconfig tap0 up

echo "waiting for dhcp to get us an address..."
sleep 15

route delete default;
route -n add $VPN_IP $GATEWAY;
route add default $VPN_GATEWAY;
```

Upon testing, I have confirmed that `GATEWAY` gets the correct value and all the other variables are set correctly. The script seems to do everything correctly up until the part where it starts changing the routes. At first I thought it was because the interface hadn't had enough time to get an IP address, so I put a pretty long wait time in to make sure it had an IP before it started trying to change routes.

Any thoughts as to why this doesn't work when put into script form?

Comment: What does it output when ran in a terminal? Add some debug echos and `||` if-fail echos?

Comment: I added a bunch of echos to give more info if the routing failed, but all three of the routing commands completed successfully

Comment: Instead of a bunch of echos, I find adding the -vx options to the she-bang line really helpful when debugging scripts (i.e. `#!/bin/bash -vx`). These two options (a) cause bash to echo each line of the input script to stdout and then (b) echo the expanded version of the line after variable expansion, etc. It can be a great help to find out exactly what commands are being executed. (see man bash > shell builtin commands > set)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: sudo doesn't work well in shell scripts as it's an interactive tool and need to prompt for a password. You might consider removing the sudo commands and running the entire script using sudo.

Comment: oops. I forgot to take those sudos out when I was copying the commands into the script. I had always run the script itself with sudo anyway so I don't think it affected it.

Nevertheless, that part of the script works correctly as I end up with the expected IP address issued from DHCP on the tap0 device